Why do I get a linker message: undefined reference to `Date::Date(int, int, int)'
Doing the problems in a popular textbook, I got a error when using a member function in a struct:

.../s09-04-02.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Date::Date(int, int, int)'

// s09-04-02.cpp simple date 
#include <iostream>
struct Date {
    int y, m, d; // year
    Date(int y, int m, int d);  // define constructor 
    void add_day(int n) ;       // declare to add n days
    int month() {return m;};    // define return month
    int day() {return d;};      // define return day
    int year() {return y;};     // define return year
};
    
int main() {
    Date birthday {1970,12,30};
    std::cout<<birthday.year()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<birthday.month()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<birthday.day()<<"\n";
}

g++ -g -o s09-04-02 s09-04-02.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXgSexK.o: in function `main':
/home/c++/Stroustrup/PPandP2nd/Ch09Classes/s09-04-02.cpp:13: undefined reference to `     Date::Date(int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:5: d09-04-02] Error 1

It seemed clear that the function with the matching name was defined. Why was it missing when when the linker went looking for it?
Looked at several articles on Stack Exchange and ...
Including this very complete (and long) article
what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

You declared 2 functions you didn't define: Date(int y, int m, int d); and void add_day(int n) ;. If you delete Date(int y, int m, int d); the compiler will do the right thing for you: https://ideone.com/QgIbct

// define constructor  You haven't defined the constructor there.  You have merely declared that it exists...somewhere.  And that's the problem.  add_day is another function that has no definition.

You are correct.  I should read the code, not the comments.  @drescherjm 's comment is especially noted because the compiler will use the default constructor if the empty declaration is provided without a definition.

Removing it worked because you kept the same order of int y, m, d; // year so Date birthday {1970,12,30}; would initialize the y, then m then d. This msdn topic will explain it much better than I can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializing-classes-and-structs-without-constructors-cpp?view=msvc-170

You have merely declared the Date constructor, so the compiler knows that it exists. But, you have not defined (implemented) its body, so the linker can't refer to it at the place where you are calling it.
You need to add that definition, eg:
struct Date {
    int y, m, d;
    Date(int y, int m, int d) : y(y), m(m), d(d) {}  // declare & define constructor 
    ...
};

Alternatively:
struct Date {
    int y, m, d;
    Date(int y, int m, int d);  // declare constructor 
    ...
};


// define constructor
Date::Date(int y, int m, int d)
    : y(y), m(m), d(d)
{
} 

(you have the same problem with add_day(), too)
